# How to exclude a specific class from Jar file but include in war file using maven-war-plugin?

Tags: spring-boot, jar, pom.xml, war, maven-war-plugin

I have a sprint-boot project "A" which has a main class which extends SpringBootServletInitializer so that war can be deployed for the same.
This library/module is also a dependent library for another project "B" which has its own main class.
In A's pom.xml, i have added the following in pom.xml:

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>copyLib</warName>
                    <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                    <classesClassifier>classes</classesClassifier>
                    <packagingExcludes>
                        WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/jetty-*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/websocket-*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.websocket*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/javax-websocket*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/snakeyaml*.jar
            </packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

With the above plugin both war & jar is getting created.

Now what i want is main class of A does not get included in jar but should get added in war so that when same jar is used by B, main class does not get invoked. I tried many approaches but failed. I even tried using @Profile but that also does not work